# Create variable that counts progressively how many times an ID is repeated in a day

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

So I have a table that has different days and didfferent hours in each day, and the client ID can appear multiple times per day.

```
data Data1;
   infile datalines delimiter=',';
   input date :ddmmyy10. ID $ time :time8. $ ;
   format date ddmmyy10.;  
   format time time8.; 
datalines;
05/11/2020,1000,8:15:23
05/11/2020,1000,8:20:10
05/11/2020,1001,8:21:10
05/11/2020,1001,9:05:15
05/11/2020,1001,10:30:20
06/11/2020,1002,8:26:10
06/11/2020,1003,8:27:10
06/11/2020,1003,9:40:01
;
```

I want to output another column that is called "Attempts" which would look like this:

```
data Data1;
   infile datalines delimiter=',';
   input date :ddmmyy10. ID $ time :time8. $ Attempt;
   format date ddmmyy10.;  
   format time time8.; 
datalines;
05/11/2020,1000,8:15:23,1
05/11/2020,1000,8:20:10,2
05/11/2020,1001,8:21:10,1
05/11/2020,1001,9:05:15,2
05/11/2020,1001,10:30:20,3
06/11/2020,1002,8:26:10,1
06/11/2020,1003,8:27:10,1
06/11/2020,1003,9:40:01,2
06/11/2020,1000,10:20:10,1
06/11/2020,1000,11:20:10,2
06/11/2020,1000,12:20:10,3
06/11/2020,1000,13:20:10,3
;
```

As you can see, client 1000 appears two times on day 05/11 and 4 times on 06/11, customer 1001 appears 3 imes on 05/11, customer 1002 appears one time on 06/11 and customer 1003 appears 2 times on 06/11.

I also would like that 3 is the maximum, so if a client appears more than 3 times on a day (like customer 1000 on 06/11) the value would be 3.

I don't mind using sas language or proc sql, so if anyone has an idea in either, please let me know

Comment: This is much simpler using a data step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use BY group processing and a retained variable. You can use the MIN() function to cap the counter at 3.

```
data Data1;
   infile datalines dsd;
   input date :ddmmyy. ID $ time :time. expect;
   format date ddmmyy10. time time8.; 
datalines;
05/11/2020,1000,8:15:23,1
05/11/2020,1000,8:20:10,2
05/11/2020,1001,8:21:10,1
05/11/2020,1001,9:05:15,2
05/11/2020,1001,10:30:20,3
06/11/2020,1000,10:20:10,1
06/11/2020,1000,11:20:10,2
06/11/2020,1000,12:20:10,3
06/11/2020,1000,13:20:10,3
06/11/2020,1002,8:26:10,1
06/11/2020,1003,8:27:10,1
06/11/2020,1003,9:40:01,2
;

data want;
  set data1;
  by date id ;
  retain attempt;
  if first.id then attempt=1;
  else attempt=min(3,attempt+1);
run;
```

Note: I reordered your sample data to avoid needing to add a PROC SORT step.  If your real dataset is grouped but not sorted, as in your example, you can add the NOTSORTED keyword on the BY statement and the logic will work.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I tried it with the snippet and it worked perfectly, but when I tried it with my real data it's only showing "Attempts" = 1 and no 2's and 3's. I did realize in my real data the only thing that's ordered is the date, but the ID is not grouped like in the snippet, could that be why?

Comment: You need to sort by both.  `proc sort data=data1; by date id; run;`  You could also use `by id date;` but then make sure to test for `first.date` instead of `first.id`. To get the ATTEMPT numbers in the right order include TIME in the sorting step.  `by id date time;`.

Comment: Thank you! Figured that was what's missing :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can still consider `proc sql` using a conditional correlated aggregate query:

```
data Data1;
   infile datalines delimiter=',';
   input date :ddmmyy10. ID $ time :time8. ;
   format date ddmmyy10.;  
   format time time8.; 
datalines;
05/11/2020,1000,8:15:23
05/11/2020,1000,8:20:10
05/11/2020,1001,8:21:10
05/11/2020,1001,9:05:15
05/11/2020,1001,10:30:20
06/11/2020,1002,8:26:10
06/11/2020,1003,8:27:10
06/11/2020,1003,9:40:01
06/11/2020,1000,10:20:10,1
06/11/2020,1000,11:20:10,2
06/11/2020,1000,12:20:10,3
06/11/2020,1000,13:20:10,3
;

proc sql;
    CREATE TABLE output AS
    SELECT d.date, d.ID, d.time
          , (SELECT CASE 
                         WHEN COUNT(*) > 3 
                         THEN 3 
                         ELSE COUNT(*) 
                    END FROM Data1 sub
             WHERE sub.ID = d.ID
               AND sub.date = d.date
               AND sub.time <= d.time
            ) AS attempts
    FROM Data1 d; 
quit;
```